# UiPageController and NavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

my problem is not showing navigationBar title for first view in my controller.
For next items text is showing.
My code:

```
ViewControllerEvent *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:self.index];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];
[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And ViewController code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = [self.event objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.title = [self.event objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```